# "I would like to have the results in a class that would support the following functions:..."

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

This is the xml file I want to use
I tried to create a dictionary called 'dict1'
It should contain the keys 'Pocket_substation' and 'sub_substation'
and the first key Pocket_substation should contain all the input_names and the sub_substation key should contain all the output_names.

```
<input_layer name = "Pocket_Substation"/>

<output_layer name = "sub_substation"/>

<field_mapping>

    <field input_name = "dat"  output_name="date" />

    <field input_name = "Type"  output_name="type"/>

    <field input_name = "Class"  output_name="class"/>

    <field input_name = "Land"  output_name="land"/>

    <field input_name = "status"  output_name="status"/>

    <field input_name = "descrp"  output_name="description"/>

    <field input_name = "Loc"  output_name="location"/>

    <field input_name = "voltage" output_name="voltage"/>

    <field input_name = "name"  output_name="owner_name"/>


    <field input_name = "Remarks"  output_name="remarks"/>

</field_mapping>
```

and to select all the input_names i wrote

```
for elem in tree.iter(tag='field'):

print elem.attrib

for ele in elem.attrib(tag='input_name'):

    print ele.attrib
```

but it prints only the first values. Someone help me to solve this
the functions in the code:

```
def read_field(xml_node, name):

return [child.get(name) for child in xml_node.iter('field')]

def read_map(xml_node):

f = root.attrib

dict1 = {f['name']:['input_layer','output_layer','fields']}

dict1[f['name']][0] = {'input_layer':root.find('input_layer').get('name')}

dict1[f['name']][1] = {'output_layer':root.find('output_layer').get('name')}

for child in xml_node:

    if child.tag == 'field_mapping':

        fields = {field_name : read_field(child, field_name) for field_name 

                 in ['input_name','output_name']}

        dict1[f['name']][2] = 

        {'fields':dict(zip(fields['output_name'],fields['input_name']))}

return dict1
```

Comment: Are you using ElementTree? Could you also add some more of your code, so that we can see how you access the elements?

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('substation.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

for child_of_root in root:
 print child_of_root.tag
it gives all the child roots.
for elem in tree.iter():
 print elem.tag, elem.attrib
it gives all the attributes 
but I can't separate the 'input_name' and 'output_name' attributes

Comment: @Elango I have edited the answer and showed how it is done using `ElementTree`. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to wrap you XML entries in something like ..., because otherwise it is not syntactically correct.

Other than that you can parse your mapping like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def read_field_attributes(xml_node, name):
    return [child.get(name) for child in xml_node.iter('field')]

def read_mapping(xml_node):
    # reset the variables
    input_layer = None
    output_layer = None
    fields = dict()
    # loop over the first level nodes and store the values
    for child in xml_node:
        if child.tag == 'field_mapping':
            # read the input and output fields separate but in order
            fields = {field_name : read_field_attributes(child, field_name) for field_name in ['input_name', 'output_name']}
        elif child.tag == 'input_layer':
            # read the name of the input layer
            input_layer = child.get('name')
        elif child.tag == 'output_layer':
            # read the name of the output layer
            output_layer = child.get('name')
    # if all the information is provided, build the mapping
    if input_layer is not None and output_layer is not None and len(fields) == 2:
        return {
            input_layer : fields['input_name'],
            output_layer : fields['output_name'],
        }
    # otherwise, return an empty dictionary
    return {}

tree = ET.parse('substation.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(read_mapping(root))
```

The output would be

```
{
    'Pocket_Substation': 
        ['dat', 'Type', 'Class', 'Land', 'status', 'descrp', 'Loc', 'voltage', 'name', 'Remarks'], 
    'sub_substation': 
        ['date', 'type', 'class', 'land', 'status', 'description', 'location', 'voltage', 'owner_name', 'remarks']
}
```

However, parsing and storing the input and output parameters is a bit dangerous, because one of the fields could have input and no output or vice versa and you would not know about it during the parsing. Instead, I would advice to use a dictionary to map inputs to outputs, so that each input corresponds to an output and only one.

Comment: thanks @Pablo Gutierrez Marques. Got the output I wanted. Thanks for the immediate help

Comment: Hi @Pablo Gutierrez Marques. I need the output values in dictionary format.

Comment: The `return {
            input_layer : fields['input_name'],
            output_layer : fields['output_name'],
        }` is a dictionary. Does this work or you need a different structure?

Comment: No. It worked. Thanks again @ Pablo Gutierrez Marques

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in class?

Comment: @Elango Edit the question with something like: "I would like to have the results in a class that would support the following functions:..." and you add a signature of the functions you need and I can provide something

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing `xml`. It is much convenient.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_xml, 'xml')

print {soup.find('input_layer').get('name'): [item.get('input_name') for item in soup.find_all('field')]}
```

It will give you an output like this:

```
{u'Pocket_Substation': [u'dat',
  u'Type',
  u'Class',
  u'Land',
  u'status',
  u'descrp',
  u'Loc',
  u'voltage',
  u'name',
  u'Remarks']}
```

If you want to use `xml` module for this you can approach like this:

```
{root.find('input_layer').get('name'): [item.get('input_name') for item in list(root.find('field_mapping'))]}
```

this will give you the same output.

Comment: How the dictionary should look like?